# The type 'local:VideoView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built

Tags: android-videoview

I have added the assembly "Plugin.MediaManager.Forms" But it is showing the following error-"Failed to resolve assembly: 'Plugin.MediaManager.Forms, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'     ,
The type 'local:VideoView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
Have added my code in the comment.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Plugin.MediaManager.Forms;assembly=Plugin.MediaManager.Forms"
             x:Class="VideoApp.Views.Videoplay">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <local:VideoView></local:VideoView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

Comment: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MediaManager.Forms;assembly=MediaManager.Forms"

USED the above plugin and it helped